Comparative statics and Implicit function theorem with 3 equations
I have solved an optimization problem which yields the following set of first order conditions:
\begin{align}
    p_x(x,y)V(a)=k  \\
    p(x,y)V'(z)=1 \\
    p_y(x,y)V(z)=1
  \end{align}
Where x, y and z are the control variables whereas parameters $a$ and $k$ are positive real numbers. $p(\cdot)$ is a probability function, strictly increasing and strictly concave in both arguments. No assumption made on the cross-derivative (but can be made if needed). $V(\cdot)$ is also strictly increasing and strictly concave. x, y and z must be non-negative.
My objective is to find how $x^*$ responds in equilibrium to an increase in the parameter k , i.e. the sign of the derivative of $x^*$  wrt k.
I'm am familiar with the implicit function theorem with one equation but I am not sure how to set it up when I have 3 equations and multiple variables affecting each other, like in this instance. Could anybody help me solve this problem, step by step?

Totally differentiate each equation with respect to $(k,x,y,z)$:
\begin{align}
V(a)[p_{xx}dx+p_{xy}dy]&=dk \tag{1}\\
V'(z)[p_xdx+p_ydy]+pV''(z)dz&=0 \tag{2}\\
V(z)[p_{xy}dx+p_{yy}dy]+p_yV'(z)dz&=0 \tag{3}
\end{align}
This system can be written in matrix form as
$$\begin{pmatrix}
V(a)p_{xx} & V(a)p_{xy} & 0\\
V'(z)p_x & V'(z)p_y & pV''(z)\\
V(z)p_{xy} & V(z)p_y & p_yV'(z)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}dx\\ dy \\ dz\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}dk\\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\tag{*}$$
and solved by inverting the $3\times3$ matrix (assuming it is invertible):
$$\begin{pmatrix}dx\\ dy \\ dz\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
V(a)p_{xx} & V(a)p_{xy} & 0\\
V'(z)p_x & V'(z)p_y & pV''(z)\\
V(z)p_{xy} & V(z)p_y & p_yV'(z)
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}dk\\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial k}\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial k}\\\frac{\partial z}{\partial k}\end{pmatrix}dk.$$
However, if you are only interested in $\partial x/\partial k$, and are doing this by hand, then this entails more working than necessary, so an alternative would be as follows:
Solving $(1)$ for $dy$ gives
$$dy=\frac{1}{V(a)p_{xy}}dk-\frac{p_{xx}}{p_{xy}}dx$$
Substituting into $\frac{p_{xy}}{V'(z)}\times (2)$ and $\frac{p_{xy}}{V(z)}\times(3)$ gives
\begin{align}
\left(p_xp_{xy}-p_yp_{xx}\right)dx+\frac{p_{xy}pV''(z)}{V'(z)}dz&=-\frac{p_y}{V(a)}dk \tag{4}\\
\left(p_{xy}^2 -p_{xx}p_{yy}\right) dx+\frac{p_{xy}p_yV'(z)}{V(z)}dz&=-\frac{p_{yy}}{V(a)}dk \tag{5}
\end{align}
Etc!
Just eliminate $dz$ from the equations to get an equation in the form $dx=Mdk$. The expression for the partial derivative you want is $M$.

The more generally applicable method that will allow you to find the derivatives of $x$, $y$, and $z$ with respect to $a$ and $k$ goes as follows:
Let $F:\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be given by
\begin{align}
F_1(a,k,x,y,z)&=p_x(x,y)V(a)-k\\
F_2(a,k,x,y,z)&=p(x,y)V'(z)-1\\
F_3(a,k,x,y,z)&=p_y(x,y)V(z)-1
\end{align}
With this notation, $F(a,k,x,y,z)=0$ is the equation that potentially defines $(x,y,z)$ as an implicit function of $(a,k)$.
The Jacobian of $F$ with respect to $(x,y,z)$ is (the same $3\times 3$ matrix as in equation $(*)$ above):
$$J_{F,(x,y,z)}\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
p_{xx}V(a) & p_{xy}V(a)& 0\\
p_xV''(x) & p_yV'(x)& pV''(z)\\
p_{xy}V(z)& p_{yy}V(z)& p_yV'(z)
\end{pmatrix}$$
and the Jacobian of $F$ with respect to $(a,k)$ is
$$J_{F,(a,k)}\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial a} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial k}\\
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial a} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial k}\\
\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial a} & \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial k}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
p_{x}(x,y)V'(a) & -1\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
If $J_{F,(x,y,z)}$ is invertible, then the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial k}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial k}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial a} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial k}
\end{pmatrix}=-[J_{F,(x,y,z)}]^{-1}J_{F,(a,k)}$$
